# How can I query Mercurial for the the revision which introduced a given file?

Tags: mercurial

Given a file name, how can I query Mercurial for the revision of the change set which introduced this file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to work with [revsets](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets)!

```
hg log -r "adds(filename.ext)"
```

The description from the help:

> "adds(pattern)":
>      Changesets that add a file matching pattern.
>     The pattern without explicit kind like "glob:" is expected to be relative to the current directory and match against a file or a directory.

Comment: I chose this answer over http://stackoverflow.com/a/25632251/107158 because I appreciate the general usefulness and elegance of revsets.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
hg log -r : -l 1 filepath
```

`hg log -r :` prints the history in reverse order, the `-l 1` switch limits the changes displayed to the first one.

Comment: I liked this answer because I wasn't aware of `-r :`, but after some consideration and a brief discussion with a teammate, I finally chose http://stackoverflow.com/a/25631851/107158 for the reason I gave in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631408/how-can-i-query-mercurial-for-the-the-revision-which-introduced-a-given-file/25632251#comment40048581_25631851.